# airflow ldap group setup for viewer profile filter

Tags: ldap, airflow

I am using ad based authentication to access the airflow  in my company , i  have created two groups in ad(ldap) for superuser_filter and data_profiler , i want to create or integrate one group like viewer which can help me to allow only read only access of dags and other system information for the users who are part of this viewer group .

has someone already did it ?

group_member_attr = memberOf superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-super-users,OU=Groups,OU=RWC,OU=US,OU=NORAM,DC=example,DC=com data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-data-profilers,OU=Groups,OU=RWC,OU=US,OU=NORAM,DC=example,DC=com

like these two above groups , similarly we can create one for viewer .

if its not already available can someone please help me how can i implement it in the current setup .

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think this type of question is off-topic for this site if you review the [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) it might help. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for this.

Comment: Thanks , I have posted the question on server fault .